# Custom FSRM File Management Task file name variable

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows

Trying to create a custom file management task in Server 2012 R2 to move some files (not file expiration).

Looks like the possible variables I can insert into my command arguments are pretty limited:
[image]

Right now I'm doing this which works fine: `mv [Source File Path] "C:\somefolder\$(split-path [Source File Path] -Leaf)"` but I'm just surprised there isn't an out of the box variable for the file name. Are there any more variables available or is it just the ones in the pick list? Is it possible to create a custom variable that would be populated in the pick list?